# Cannot convert VGG16 layers to sequential

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to do image classification using VGG16 pre-trained model. For the same, I did the following:

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
```

The type of the model is as follows:

```
type(vgg16_model)
```

And the result is:

```
tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model
```

Then, I defined a Sequential model as:

```
model = Sequential()
```

Then, I tried to convert the `vgg16_model` into sequential by:

```
for layer in vgg16_model.layers:
    model.add(layer)
```

It shows me an error as follows:

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: < tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x1ddbce5e80>**
```

It would be great if anyone could help me on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

My mistake was that my import statement was:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
```

Then, again, when I initialised the model, I called it again as:

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
```

So, a stupid mistake on my part. The fix is as follows:

```
vgg16_model = VGG16()
```

I realise that the problem is very specific and might not be so much useful to the community. Still, I am posting the solution just in case someone else faces it again.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to this problem as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One simpler way to do this is to pass the layers directly to the Sequential model instance, instead of using a for loop:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

vgg = VGG16(weights='imagenet', ...)
model = Sequential(vgg.layers)
```